# iterating a nested js object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the jsonplaceholder as my state for react app. when I iterate through the nested object to display I could not make it work. For example I take two of this

```
state = {
post: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leanne Graham",
    username: "Bret",
    email: "Sincere@april.biz",
    address: {
      street: "Kulas Light",
      suite: "Apt. 556",
      city: "Gwenborough",
      zipcode: "92998-3874",
      geo: {
        lat: "-37.3159",
        lng: "81.1496"
      }
    },
    phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    website: "hildegard.org",
    company: {
      name: "Romaguera-Crona",
      catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ervin Howell",
    username: "Antonette",
    email: "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    address: {
      street: "Victor Plains",
      suite: "Suite 879",
      city: "Wisokyburgh",
      zipcode: "90566-7771",
      geo: {
        lat: "-43.9509",
        lng: "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    phone: "010-692-6593 x09125",
    website: "anastasia.net",
    company: {
      name: "Deckow-Crist",
      catchPhrase: "Proactive didactic contingency",
      bs: "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
]
};
```

I used this approach

```
class post extends Component {
  state ={ … }
  render() {
    let nestedObj = null;

if (this.state.post) {
  nestedObj = this.state.post.map(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj.company).map(e => {
      let company= `${obj.company[e]}`;
      console.log(company);
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>{company}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  });
  console.log(nestedObj);
}
return(
  <p>{nestedObj}</p>
  )
 }
```

this doesnot display on the client eventhough it console.log it in terminal, I try to use the hasOwnProperty and it gives me back [object object]. Second I notice if I use Object.entries and forEach instead of object.keys and map respectively it console it but does not display it, which approach is appropriate?

my tragets are the address and company.
 Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are missing `return` before `Object.keys`. Right know you are not returning anything from the `map` callback.

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling it work. if I were to get name, username and email should I have to make another like the nestedObj var to map it or it can handle with that variable?

Comment: What is your expected output? what should print on the screen by HTML?

Comment: I want to print on like the name, email, phone,website. If I just put {obj.name} in the <li> tag it print 3 times until it finish the loop of object company but I want just one time. how do I do this?